# Nested for loop in a two-dimension array

Tags: c++

I have learned how to print out each element in a two-dimensional array

```
int arr[3][3] = {....};
for ( auto &row : arr){
     for ( auto col : row)
        cout<<col<<endl;
}
```

I understand that the &row in the outer for loop has to be a reference. Otherwise, row will become a pointer pointing to array arr's first element which is an array of 3 ints.

Based on this, I thought the following code could work but it didn't

```
for( auto row : arr ){
    for ( auto col:*row)
         cout<<col<<endl;
}
```

It gives me the error about the inner for loop

```
no callable 'begin' function found for type 'int'
```

Did I miss something here?

Comment: row is an array of 3 ints, which can be iterated. *row is an int, you can't loop through an integer.

Comment: @tntxtnt `row` is a pointer, not an array (in the code that gives the error).

Comment: Ah I didn't see row is not a reference in the second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of `arr` has type `int[3]`.

When `row` is a reference, it gets type `int (&) [3]`, which can be iterated over. But when it isn't a reference, the `int[3]` array decays to a pointer to its first element, so `row` has type `int*`, which can't be used in a range-for loop.

Your code is attempting to iterate over `*row`, which has type `int`, leading to the error.